# How to check whether receiver is damaged?

Tags: receiver, long-range-drone, antenna

I am a beginner. I have bought RadioMaster TX12 and turned it on without an antenna and with an extra module for 915mhz for 1 minute. Internal RF was not off. How can I check whether something got damaged? I dont have a drone yet. Should I buy another one RadioMaster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have a receiver, you can do a range test.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-7_YfRSoXik